# Approximating periodic functions

Tags: neural-network, universal-approximation-theorem

I am trying to understand if neural networks can be trained to approximate periodic functions well. Here's the toy problem I have in mind:

Consider function `clock(seconds_since_t0)` that returns a vector of 4 values, that correspond to what digital clock would display assuming `t0` is 0 days 00:00:00.

I wrote a simple dataset in PyTorch, that samples values of the `clock` function on `seconds_since_t0` from 0 to 30 years:

```py
import torch
from torch import device as Device
from torch.utils.data import IterableDataset
from typing import Optional

MS_IN_SECOND = 1000
MS_IN_MINUTE = 60 * MS_IN_SECOND
MS_IN_HOUR = 60 * MS_IN_MINUTE
MS_IN_DAY = 24 * MS_IN_HOUR
MS_IN_YEAR = 365 * MS_IN_DAY


def _msec_to_clock(msec):
    msec_val = msec % 1000
    seconds = torch.div(msec, 1000, rounding_mode='floor')
    sec_val = seconds % 60
    minutes = torch.div(seconds, 60, rounding_mode='floor')
    min_val = minutes % 60
    hours = torch.div(minutes, 60, rounding_mode='floor')
    hour_val = hours % 24
    days = torch.div(hours, 24, rounding_mode='floor')

    return torch.cat([days, hour_val, min_val, sec_val, msec_val], dim=1)


class Clock(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, batch_size: int = 1, device: Optional[Device] = None,
                 min_msec: int = -60 * MS_IN_YEAR,
                 max_msec: int = 60 * MS_IN_YEAR):
        super().__init__()

        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.device = device
        self.min_msec = min_msec
        self.max_msec = max_msec

    def sample(self):
        msec = torch.randint(self.min_msec, self.max_msec, (self.batch_size, 1),
                             device=self.device, dtype=torch.int64)
        expected = _msec_to_clock(msec)
        return msec.to(torch.float64) / 1000, expected.to(torch.float32)

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            yield self.sample()
```

I used MSE loss for clock components.

I tried to fit it with a simple 4 layer 128 unit network and with a similarly sized [SIREN](https://vsitzmann.github.io/siren/). Both were essentially unable to approximate with error being ~1.5e+7 (untrained network gives ~3e+7).

I searched for other works related to reproduction of periodic functions, but all I found was either sequence modeling, or attempts at other periodic activations similar to SIREN like `x + sin(x) ** 2`, which yielded no further improvement.

Are there better approaches?